# android is it standard to make buttons text and other views text larger in tablet size?

Tags: android, user-interface, user-experience

Is it standard to make buttons text and other views text larger in tablet size? I make dimens.xml for different device sizes and make different text sizes for different device sizes. for examle in normal dimens file:

```
<dimen name="small_text_mobile">14dp</dimen>
```

and for large size dimens file:

```
<dimen name="small_text_mobile">18dp</dimen>
```

and use this dimens for my textViews and buttons , extra..I want to know if it is standard? or no need for that and **texts of** views like buttons should be in same size in different device sizes?

Answer (score 1):

The unit used (dp) will convert the button and layout sizes to appropriate pixel sizes on the actual device (making them independent of actual device screen size). Therefore, on a small device it will look relatively similar to a large device. However, depending on the situation, it may be more efficient use of screen space to have different dimensions/layouts for different screen sizes. It really depends on the view being used and the level of user experience required for it. A lot of the time dp will get the job done close to what you would want. The [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) on supporting multiple screen sizes is excellent in explaining all the different situations and control a developer could have on their layouts.

Depending on the layout, it may be better practice to create multiple layouts to fit small and large screens in different orientations. It depends on the layout and how complex it is. If it looks unnatural on a certain device, I would recommend creating another layout (or applying some changes on the current one) to better fit all devices.

Comment: thank you for your answer, I know about dp. I got the answer but not all of it, part of my question was about in large sizes like tablet because we have more space is it standard and make good UX to font set sizes bigger?

Comment: @MohammadHadi I do not think there is any standard, but depending on the font it may not scale correctly. I think the best way to know for your app is to test on larger devices (use emulator if no large devices at hand). Usually, font sizes on larger devices will show up just as readable as font sizes on smaller ones, but there are always exceptoin to this rule.

Comment: @MohammadHadi can you accept this answer as it is the only one so if other people come to this they can see it

Comment: No I don`t got the answer I want